# Problems with NsTask to execute terminal command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, terminal, command, echo

Normally in the terminal I would execute this command to communicate with a serial USB device.

echo -e '\xFF\x01\x01' > /dev/cu.usbserial-A8003YzT

I'm trying to do this from within a cocoa app using NStask, but I'm getting no love for some reason.

Heres my code:

```
- (IBAction) doCommand:(id)sender{
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];

    [task setLaunchPath:@"/bin/echo"];

    [task setArguments:
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-e '\\xFF\\x01\\x01' > /dev/cu.usbserial-A8003YzT", nil]];


    [task launch];

    [task release];
}}
```

I know the code is essentially working, as I've executed other terminal commands with the same script.....not sure why I can't get the echo to fire....perhaps I'm missing somthing simple?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to send `'\xFF\x01\x01' > /dev/cu.usbserial-A8003YzT` as the first argument to `echo`, but that's not what happens when you run that command from a shell prompt. Only the first, quoted part is sent as an argument to echo. Bash interprets the `>` itself, captures the output from the echo command, and redirects it to the indicated file - in this case, a file that represents a usb device.

If you want to run an `NSTask` that will interpret a shell command with redirects, pipes, and such, you'll need to use `/bin/sh` as the launch path, and `-c`, `your shell command` as arguments.

Alternatively, you could skip the `NSTask` altogether, and simply open an `NSFileHandle` to the device file, then send the three-byte sequence you want to send it. Echo is handy for interactive debugging stuff like this in a terminal, but launching an external task in your app, just to write three bytes to a file, is pretty drastic overkill... :-)

Comment: +1 for "Alternatively..."  NSTasks that need to launch a shell are a **Bad Idea** in my experience.  For one thing, they break NSLog for the rest of program execution.

Comment: @Sherm....Yes that took care of the issue. works now. I thought for sure I was not understanding the proper function of running the command properly.  thanks for clearing that up.  I'm fairly new to Obj-c  so I'll give the NSFileHandle a look.  Sounds like it's a better way of doing it, just not sure how yet....    @Richard, thanks for the heads up, I've read the same thing, and will be looking at NSfilehandle as a better alternative  Thanks folks!